# Adding column in dataframes in Pandas using data in existing Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following Dataframe looks like in below image:

[image]

I need to add one more column 'Key' to existing Dataframe such as it looks like Dataframe in below image:

[image]

Is there a way to create a Column "Key" based on columns Field and Seq

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should provide real code in your questions (not pictures). Read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get responses. You can also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: You can do df['Key']="blah" and then can change every value of row by "loc" on index .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Field': ['Indicator', 'A', 'B', 'Code', '1', '2', '3', 'Name', 'Address'],
                   'Count': [26785, 785, 26000, 12345, 45, 300, 12000, 12312, 1212],
                   'Seq': [1.0, 1.1, 1.1, 2.0, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 3.0, 4.0]})

sep = df.loc[df['Seq'].apply(lambda x: x == int(x)), 'Field'].tolist()

df['key'] = pd.Series(np.where(~df['Field'].isin(sep), None, df['Field'])).ffill()
df.loc[df['Field'] != df['key'], 'key'] += '+' + df['Field']

#    Count      Field  Seq          key
# 0  26785  Indicator  1.0    Indicator
# 1    785          A  1.1  Indicator+A
# 2  26000          B  1.1  Indicator+B
# 3  12345       Code  2.0         Code
# 4     45          1  2.1       Code+1
# 5    300          2  2.1       Code+2
# 6  12000          3  2.1       Code+3
# 7  12312       Name  3.0         Name
# 8   1212    Address  4.0      Address
```

**Explanation**

- Add a 'key' column and replace values not in `sep` with `None`, then use `ffill()` to fill the `None` values.
- Update 'key' column only where 'Field' and 'key' are misaligned.

Comment: Thanks!, can you suggest me how to generate "sep" list dynamically if data is changing every time.

Comment: Actually the list in sep should be values in Field when Seq is like 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 and so on. Not based in Field length
What would be solution for this?

Comment: Hi All these days, code is working fine and now i got a warning message: 

At this line:
sep = df.loc[df['Seq'].apply(lambda x: x == int(x)), 'Field'].tolist()

SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: @Deepak..G, There might be nothing wrong with this. It's a warning, not an error. If you google this error, you'll probably find lots of reasons but no guaranteed solution.